'Going into whoops ' in 17th century England appears to mean laughing when a good put down has been achieved. Am I right?
I figured this out from reading 17th century fiction & modern day fiction about the 17th century

Will you please add one or two examples with their source so that we can see what you mean in context?

"whoop" could refer to a range of cries: derision, encouragement, summoning/calling for attention, etc. go into also has various meanings, but you can find those in a dictionary. Without context it's impossible to distinguish between the various different meanings.

I searched Google Books for "whoops," delimited to 1500-1700, and in the first page of results found no usages that don't align with modern senses (loud cry in general). Please share what you've already found; while no one hear minds doing research, it seems that you've already done some and it's irksome to fumble around in the dark trying to replicate it.

I don't know why you think it means laughing for a particular reason.

Please put the question into the question text. The title should be a shorter summary.

This bias may just be due to the contexts where laughter occurs in literature. You probably don't find many cases of people telling jokes or watching comedies in 17th century writing.


'Going into whoops ' in 17th century England appears to mean laughing when a good put down has been achieved. Am I right?

No, you're wrong.
"Going into whoops of laughter" is not unusual. It means to laugh loudly/boisterously so as to make a whooping sound.
It is not at all specific to "when a good put down has been achieved".
OED
Whoop (n) (Also "hoop")

1. A cry of ‘whoop’, or a shout or call resembling this, used to attract attention, as a summons, or to express derision, defiance,
support or encouragement, etc., or (now usually) exuberant excitement;
2001 Being boys, we regarded swords and shields only for fighting, and
with hoops of delight were soon hammering away at each other with
them. M. Willoughby, Echo of Distant Drum vii. 86
2020 There were cheers and whoops of delight in Philadelphia's bars as
I watched this historic moment. i-Independent (Nexis) 9 November 19


Hm, I'm skeptical and await further clarification from the OP (without much hope). It appears they're asking for "into whoops" without any following "of __" as would normally be expected. I see no evidence but am totally ready to believe that this was a period idiom, just as "in his cups" would be rarer today. But I suspect more likely is that 17th-century usage was so heterogeneous that the OP has got hold of an outlier rather than a pattern.
